# How can I write a query to recursively execute with varying parameter values?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Given the following query:

```
DECLARE @14DayWindow Datetime = DATEADD(day, -14, GETDATE())
DECLARE @90DayWindow Datetime = DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())

SELECT    * 
FROM      (SELECT   ID, COUNT(ID) 
           FROM     SomeTable 
           WHERE    SomeDate > @14DayWindow 
           GROUP BY ID) as FourteenDayWindow
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   ID, COUNT(ID) 
           FROM     SomeTable 
           WHERE    SomeDate > @90DayWindow 
           GROUP BY ID) as NinetyDayWindow
ON        FourteenDayWindow.ID = NinetyDayWindow.ID
```

Is there a way to re-write this query such that the SELECT subquery doesn't have to be written out for every window of time?  Ideally I would be able to supply an arbitrary number of parameters with each result being joined in sequence.  Possible?

EDIT: Output should be something like

```
ID | FourteenDayIDCount | NinetyDayIDCount
```

Comment: What output format are you looking for?

Comment: @George.Palacios Added output format.  I also slightly modified the query to more accurately reflect the actual query I'm trying to run.  I think I oversimplified the original example.

Comment: I can think of a few ways of doing this with dynamic SQL (Building the statement up as a string then executing) but it seems very messy. What is the context? How many parameters do you need to run? Is there any reason you can't create a stored procedure that accepts a single parameter, and store results in a temptable for each run?

Comment: For the time being I need to run 3 parameters, but that may change at any time.  I may be able to use a temp table, but this query has to get materialized into a .NET object via Entity Framework, which I think is going to require a query that gives everything in one shot.

Comment: Okay no problem. Will all ID's satisfy all queries, or will the number of ID's differ each time based on the input parameter?

Comment: All ID's are fine.  It is ok to return NULL in the event an ID is not present for a certain parameter/time window.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [INLINE USER DEFINED FUNCTION](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx) for this purpose.

Have a look at Inline UDF rules:

- The RETURNS clause contains only the keyword table. You do not have to define the format of a return variable, because it is set by the format of the result set of the SELECT statement in the RETURN clause.
- There is no function_body delimited by BEGIN and END.
- The RETURN clause contains a single SELECT statement in parentheses. The result set of the SELECT statement forms the table returned by the function. The SELECT statement used in an inline function is subject to the same restrictions as SELECT statements used in views.
- The table-valued function accepts only constants or @local_variable arguments

> ```
> CREATE TABLE SomeTable(ID int, SomeDate datetime);
>
> INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES
> (1, '20170301'),(1, '20170305'),(1, '20170310'),(1, '20170315'),(1, '20170320'),(1, '20170325'),(1, '20170329'),
> (1, '20170401'),(1, '20170404'),(1, '20170412'),(1, '20170418'),(1, '20170422'),(1, '20170424'),(1, '20170430'),
> (2, '20170303'),(2, '20170308'),(2, '20170312'),(2, '20170319'),(2, '20170323'),(2, '20170325'),(2, '20170330'),
> (2, '20170405'),(2, '20170406'),(2, '20170412'),(2, '20170418'),(2, '20170422'),(2, '20170424'),(2, '20170430');
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCount(@MinDate datetime)
> RETURNS TABLE
> AS
> RETURN
>     SELECT   ID, COUNT(ID) NumID
>     FROM     SomeTable
>     WHERE    SomeDate > @MinDate
>     GROUP BY ID
> GO
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @XDays Datetime = '20170401';
> DECLARE @YDays Datetime = '20170308';
>
> SELECT t1.ID, t1.NumID as [X-Days], t2.NumID as [Y-Days]
> FROM   dbo.fnCount(@XDays) t1
> JOIN   dbo.fnCount(@YDays) t2
> ON     t1.ID = t2.ID
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | X-Days | Y-Days
> -: | -----: | -----:
>  1 |      6 |     12
>  2 |      7 |     12
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=34719e45d8078bdaaa76c875cee6f64e)*

Comment: Very useful!  This does move the bulk of the SQL to a function, which definitely cleans things up, but is there a way to do this so that JOINs don't have to be explicitly written?  Something like calling the UDF in a FOR loop that JOINs each result?  This may not be possible, in which case your solution is probably the best we can do.

Comment: Well, you can move the JOIN clause into the function, and add a second parameter. SELECT * FROM dbo.fnCount(@XDays, @YDays);